# Could not open connection - Spring MVC 4.x - MySql 8

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I have updated my MySQL from 5.x to 8.x. Also changed the relating versions in POM file. Once I try to start the application, my application start with JDBC connection error which is pasted below.

```
<properties>
        <springVersion>4.2.4.RELEASE</springVersion>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <dbGroupId>mysql</dbGroupId>
        <dbArtifactId>mysql-connector-java</dbArtifactId>
        <dbArtifactVersion>8.0.11</dbArtifactVersion>
    </properties>
```

The above is my versions used,

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not
>   open connection
>         at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:221)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:550)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
>         at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:201)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:395)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:158)
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
>         ... 51 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Client does not support
>   authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL
>   client)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
>         at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
>         at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
>         ... 62 more
>       Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server;
>   consider upgrading MySQL client
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:894)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3808)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1256)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2032)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
>         at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
>         at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
>         ... 66 more

Any inputs on how to resolve this issue will be truly helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update the database user’s password using the OLD_PASSWORD function of MySQL. For example:

```
[chris@office ~]$ mysql -u root -p mysql

Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 267
Server version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.1 (Ubuntu)

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use mysql;
Database changed

mysql> update user set Password=OLD_PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='username';

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Refer this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html

Comment: When I am executing above query its throwing error:  ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'. Strangely the user table don't have a password field.                                        Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL this my installed version of mysql

Comment: ALTER USERE 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'; is working